# Sparksql: Json array maintaining order of elements

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some json data where one of the elements is an array. Here is a sample dataset:

> {"name":"Michael", "schools":[{"sname":"stanford", "year":2010}{"sname":"berkeley", "year":2012}, {"sname":"mit", "year":2016}]}
>
> {"name":"Andy", "schools":[{"sname":"ucsb", "year":2011}, {"sname":"ucsd", "year":2015}]]}

I want to use name as key and for a given name, I want to combine all the school names in the order they are present in the array.

Here is the desired o/p:

> michael, "stanford  berkeley  mit"
>
> Andy "ucsb  ucsd"

Here is my code:

```
val people = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
val flattened = people.select($"name", explode($"schools").as("schools_flat"))
val schools = flattened.select("name", "schools_flat.sname")
```

scala> schools.show()

+-------+--------+

|   name|   sname|

+-------+--------+

|Michael|stanford|

|Michael|berkeley|

|Michael|     mit|

+-------+--------+

Unfortunately, when I group this by key, I am not sure if order will be retained (most likely not). I don't want to the school names for Michael to be reorderd, they should appear as they were present in the original json array. Any help with this will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why explode and group instead of select?

```
people.select("name", "schools.sname")
```

It will preserve order as you want.

Comment: That gives me sname as sname: array<string>: [stanford, berkeley, mit]. How do I get string "stanford, berkeley, mit". I tried udf  , but that fails.

 val test = people.select("name", "schools.sname")
val getConcatenated = udf( (snames:  Array[String]) => { snames.mkString(" ") } )
       val test_cat = test.withColumn(col("name"), getConcatenated(col("sname"))

Comment: This works fine.
val people = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
 val test = people.select("name", "schools.sname") 
 val getConcatenated = udf( (first:  Seq[String]) => { first.mkString(" ") } )
  val test_cat = newtest.withColumn("sname_concat", getConcatenated(col("sname"))).select("name", "sname_concat")

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what was asked in the question.

```
 val people = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
 val test = people.select("name", "schools.sname") 
 val getConcatenated = udf( (first:  Seq[String]) => { first.mkString(" ") } )
 val test_cat = newtest.withColumn("sname_concat", getConcatenated(col("sname"))).select("name", "sname_concat")
```